# Finding valid phone numbers in text, no numbers found

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a program which checks a string to ensure whether it is a valid phone number(such as 415-555-1011)

```
def isPhoneNumber(text):
    if len(text)!= 12:
        return False
    for i in range(0,3):
        if not text[i].isdecimal():
            return False
        if text[3]!='-':
            return False
    for i in range(4,7):
        if text[i].isdecimal():
            return False
        if text[7]!='-':
            return False
    for i in range(8,12):
        if not text[i].decimal():
            return False
        return True

message = 'Call me at 415-555-1011 tomorrow. 415-555-9999 is my office.'
for i in range(len(message)):
    chunk = message[i:i+12]
    if isPhoneNumber(chunk):
        print('Phone number found: ' + chunk)

print('Done')
```

I should get the following output

```
Phone number found: 415-555-1011
Phone number found: 415-555-9999
Done
```

But I am getting only

```
Done
```

I am not getting the first two lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `not` in your second loop:

```
for i in range(4,7):
    if text[i].isdecimal():
        return False
```

In your last loop you use `text[i].decimal()` instead of `text[i].isdecimal()`.

This returns `False` when any of those characters **are** digits. You wanted to use:

```
for i in range(4,7):
    if not text[i].isdecimal():
        return False
```

You also test for a dash character at the next position for each iteration in each of those number loops (you only need to test *after* those loops), and your `return True` at the end needs to be moved out of that loop too (you only test for a digit at position 8).

You don't need to test each individual character; you could just use a slice:

```
def isPhoneNumber(text):
    if len(text) != 12:
        return False
    if not text[:3].isdecimal():
        return False
    if text[3] != '-':
        return False
    if not text[4:7].isdecimal():
        return False
    if text[7] != '-':
        return False
    if not text[8:12].isdecimal():
        return False
    return True
```

You could simplify all this by using a regular expression:

```
import re

phone_numbers = re.compile(r'\b\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}\b')

for number in phone_numbers.findall(message):
    print('Phone number found:', number)
```

Note that this pattern actually prohibits the phone number to be part of a longer set of numbers (your code would find phone numbers in `0014213012345-444-123244214324`; all that is required is a middle group of 3 digits surrounded by dashes and a 3 digits prefix and 4 digit postfix). The `\b` pattern requires there to be non-word characters (anything but letters, digits or underscores) before and after the matched phone number.

Comment: Actually I didnt even typed "isdecimal" in the third loop

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can try this logic:-

```
def msg_phone():
    message = 'Call me at 415-555-1011 tomorrow. 415-555-9999 is my office.'
    number=re.findall('[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}',message)
    for i in number:
        print('Phone number found:',i)
    print('Done')
```

The code length is lot less,and so is the complication.